# Simple Javascript algorithm

Tags: javascript

I'm stuck trying to create a method that checks the value of a parameter `x` and then returns a number.

```
If x is 0, 1 or 2 -> return 0
If x is 3, 4 or 5 -> return 1
If x is 6, 7 or 8 -> return 2
```

etc ...

Anyone ?

Comment: `function(x) { return Math.floor(x/3);}` ?

Comment: You've pretty much already written it!

Comment: [`if...else if...else`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else). Is it the assessment of the number that you're stuck with, or how to create that as a *method* of a Node/Object/String or whatever?

Comment: @DavidThomas Did you notice a small `etc...` below the code?

Comment: @Teemu: yes. Your point is..?

Comment: @DavidThomas Afaik `etc` means that the list is going to continue, how far, nobody knows. `if...else` approach would not be very DRY...

Comment: And without knowing more about the 'etc' we can't post a DRY answer (Kevin, and Hazaart's suggestions both work only in the specified range of the question so far because of that).

Comment: With "etc ..." I mean the value of x can be any number greater than zero. Downvotes seriously?

Comment: You may wish to look unto the `switch` keyword. The current approach will only work if (a) you assume no gaps in the numbers that are valid input and (b) you always want to return a (truncated) integer representing the input/3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the result of the division of x by 3. In javascript you can achieve this like this:

```
function foo(x) {
    return Math.floor(x/3);
}
```

Comment: I might add a quick little explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Call this function like **myval(2) or myval(4)** by passing any value you want

```
 function myval(x) { 
if(x===0 || x===1 || x==2)
  return 0;
if(x===3 || x===4 || x==5)
  return 1;
if(x===6 || x===7 || x==8)
  return 2
}
```

Comment: any value you want as long as it's between 0 and 8